# Data from Three MySQL table to one master table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three customer tables:

example:

```
customers_1, customers_2, customers_3
```

And want to create a new master table which will have ONLY the LATEST UPDATED record of a single customer.

One customer can have 1 record in all three tables.
One customer can have multiple records in all three tables.
One customer can have ONLY 1 record in any one table.

```
'mobile_no' is used to identify uniqueness. 
'updated_at' is used to know the latest record.
```

I am going to write it in PHP. I just want to know what is the best approach.

Note: Assume that one table (say `customers_1`) will always have more records than the other two.
Example:

```
customers_1: 500000 records
customers_2: 250000 records
customers_3: 220000 records
```

Comment: Do you want to to union the three tables and stop using them (start using the master table only), or keep updating the three tables and have a view that show the unioned data?

Comment: Actually the three tables will keep getting new entries. But no entries can be edited in any of the three tables.

And yeah, we will be using master customer table.

Yes. We want a union of all three tables. Removing the duplicates and keeping only LATEST records

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION to aggregate the three tables into one, and then query the most recet record of each customer

something like this should do the work:

```
WITH all_customers AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM customers_1
  UNION
  SELECT *
  FROM customers_2
  UNION
  SELECT *
  FROM customers_3
    )
SELECT ac.*
FROM (
  SELECT mobile_no, MAX(updated_at) as latest_date
  FROM all_customers) latest
LEFT JOIN all_customers ac
ON ac.mobile_no = latest.mobile_no AND ac.updated_at = latest.latest_date
```

and if you want to use this query frequently you can create a view

```
CREATE VIEW latest_customers AS
-- enter query here
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest window functions:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by mobile_no order by updated_at) as seqnum
      from ((select c.* from customers_1
            ) union all
            (select c.* from customers_2
            ) union all
            (select c.* from customers_3
            )
           ) c
      ) c
where seqnum = 1;
```

You may not want to use `select *`.  It is typically better to list all the columns that you want.